# django-cms install error ".pyc not found "

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-cms

Getting below exception while trying to install django cms. Please help

```
E:\Workspace\cms>pip install django-cms
Collecting django-cms
  Using cached django_cms-3.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: django-treebeard>=4.0.1 in c:\users\satish.sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from django-cms)
Requirement already satisfied: djangocms-admin-style>=1.0 in c:\users\satish.sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from django-cms)
Requirement already satisfied: django-sekizai>=0.7 in c:\users\satish.sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from django-cms)
Requirement already satisfied: Django<1.10,>=1.8 in c:\users\satish.sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from django-cms)
Requirement already satisfied: django-classy-tags>=0.7.2 in c:\users\satish.sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from django-cms)
Requirement already satisfied: django-formtools>=1.0 in c:\users\satish.sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from django-cms)
Installing collected packages: django-cms
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\satish.sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\satish.sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\users\satish.sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\users\satish.sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "c:\users\satish.sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "c:\users\satish.sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "c:\users\satish.sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "c:\users\satish.sharma\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\shutil.py", line 115, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\satish.sharma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\cms\\test_utils\\project\\extensionapp\\migrations\\__pycache__\\0003_multitablepageextension_multitablepageextensionparent_multitabletitleextension_multitabletitleextens.cpython-35.pyc'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may not be django-cms issue but Windows maximum path length issue (which is 260 characters).

If you are on Windows 10, you should be able to remove the limitation:

1. Open Group Policy Editor (Press Windows Key and type gpedit.msc and hit Enter key.
2. Navigate to the following directory:  Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem > NTFS.
3. Click Enable NTFS long paths option and enable it.

Source: https://mspoweruser.com/ntfs-260-character-windows-10/

Comment: Great! Please mark my answer accordingly if it solved your problem